# I made a script and I have a problem connecting to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I made a simple table form, but I don't know where I made a mistake. Below is the code.

Please give me some help.

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once 'baza.php';

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Błąd połączenia z bazą danych: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }

    $connection->close();
    ?>`

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>System zarządzania danymi samochodowymi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Wyszukaj po numerze VIN">
        <button onclick="search()">Szukaj</button>
        <select id="pageSize">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
        <label for="pageSize">wyników na stronę</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
        <form action="save_data.php" method="POST">
            <label for="dataPrzyjecia">Data przyjęcia:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dataPrzyjecia" name="dataPrzyjecia">
            <label for="dataWykonania">Data wykonania:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dataWykonania" name="dataWykonania">
            <label for="dataOddania">Data oddania samochodu:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dataOddania" name="dataOddania">
            <label for="numerVIN">Numer VIN:</label>
            <input type="text" id="numerVIN" name="numerVIN">
            <label for="przebieg">Przebieg:</label>
            <input type="number" id="przebieg" name="przebieg">
            <label for="imieOdbierajacego">Imię osoby odbierającej samochód:</label>
            <input type="text" id="imieOdbierajacego" name="imieOdbierajacego">
            <label for="daneKontaktowe">Dane kontaktowe:</label>
            <input type="text" id="daneKontaktowe" name="daneKontaktowe">
            <label for="wykonywaneZadania">Co trzeba wykonać:</label>
            <input type="text" id="wykonywaneZadania" name="wykonywaneZadania">
            <label for="wykonaneZadania">Co zostało wykonane:</label>
            <input type="text" id="wykonaneZadania" name="wykonaneZadania">
            <label for="uwagi">Uwagi:</label>
            <input type="text" id="uwagi" name="uwagi">       
            <button type="submit">Zapisz</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="data-list">
        <h2>Dane samochodowe</h2>
        <?php
            // Kod PHP pobierający dane z bazy danych i wyświetlający je w postaci tabeli
            $host = 'localhost'; // Adres serwera bazy danych
            $username = 'srv344_dane'; // Login do phpMyAdmin
            $password = 'b6FJtM9k86Tyky4JGWeV'; // Hasło do phpMyAdmin
            $database = 'srv344_dane'; // Nazwa bazy danych

            $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM samochody";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo '<table>';
                echo '<tr><th>Data przyjęcia</th><th>Data wykonania</th><th>Data oddania samochodu</th><th>Numer VIN</th><th>Przebieg</th><th>Imię osoby odbierającej samochód</th><th>Dane kontaktowe</th><th>Co trzeba wykonać</th><th>Co zostało wykonane</th><th>Uwagi</th></tr>';
                $color = "#D9D9D9";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<tr style="background-color: ' . $color . '">';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["dataPrzyjecia"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["dataWykonania"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["dataOddania"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["numerVIN"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["przebieg"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["imieOdbierajacego"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["daneKontaktowe"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["wykonywaneZadania"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["wykonaneZadania"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["uwagi"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td><button onclick="edit(' . $row["id"] . ')">Edytuj</button></td>';
                    echo '<td><button onclick="delete(' . $row["id"] . ')">Usuń</button></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $color = ($color == "#D9D9D9") ? "#FFFFFF" : "#D9D9D9";
                }
                echo '</table>';
            } else {
                echo "Brak danych.";
            }

            $conn->close();
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**baza.php**

```
<?php
// Dane do połączenia z bazą danych
$host = 'localhost'; // Adres serwera bazy danych
$username = 'srv344_dane'; // Login do phpMyAdmin
$password = 'b6FJtM9k86Tyky4JV'; // Hasło do phpMyAdmin
$database = 'srv344_dane'; // Nazwa bazy danych

// ... Tutaj możesz dodać inne zmienne z danymi, jeśli potrzebujesz
?>
```

**save_data.php**

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

?>
<?php
// Pobierz dane z formularza
$dataPrzyjecia = $_POST['dataPrzyjecia'];
$dataWykonania = $_POST['dataWykonania'];
$dataOddania = $_POST['dataOddania'];
$numerVIN = $_POST['numerVIN'];
$przebieg = $_POST['przebieg'];
$imieOdbierajacego = $_POST['imieOdbierajacego'];
$daneKontaktowe = $_POST['daneKontaktowe'];
$wykonywaneZadania = $_POST['wykonywaneZadania'];
$wykonaneZadania = $_POST['wykonaneZadania'];
$uwagi = $_POST['uwagi'];

// Utwórz połączenie z bazą danych
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "moja_baza";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Sprawdź połączenie
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Przygotuj zapytanie SQL z parametrami
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO samochody (dataPrzyjecia, dataWykonania, dataOddania, numerVIN, przebieg, imieOdbierajacego, daneKontaktowe, wykonywaneZadania, wykonaneZadania, uwagi) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Sprawdź, czy przygotowanie zapytania się powiodło
if ($stmt === false) {
    die("Error: " . $conn->error);
}

// Przypisz wartości parametrów
$stmt->bind_param("ssssisssss", $dataPrzyjecia, $dataWykonania, $dataOddania, $numerVIN, $przebieg, $imieOdbierajacego, $daneKontaktowe, $wykonywaneZadania, $wykonaneZadania, $uwagi);

// Wykonaj zapytanie
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

// Zamknij połączenie i zapytanie
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

// Przekieruj do strony głównej po zapisaniu danych
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
?>
```

**phpMyAdmin**

```
CREATE TABLE samochody (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dataPrzyjecia DATE,
    dataWykonania DATE,
    dataOddania DATE,
    numerVIN VARCHAR(20),
    przebieg INT,
    imieOdbierajacego VARCHAR(50),
    daneKontaktowe VARCHAR(100),
    wykonywaneZadania VARCHAR(255),
    wykonaneZadania VARCHAR(255),
    uwagi VARCHAR(255)
)
```

**After filling out the form, the save_data.php page appears and displays an error:**
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /home/srv344/domains/xxx.pl/public_html/daneserwisu/save_data.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /home/srv344/domains/xxx.pl/public_html/daneserwisu/save_data.php(26): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'moja_baza') #1 {main} thrown in /home/srv344/domains/xxx.pl/public_html/daneserwisu/save_data.php on line 26

It seems that connecting to the database has failed.

Where did I make a mistake?

I entered the database data 100% correctly.

Comment: Terminology note: PhpMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a web based administration tool for managing MySQL databases. (It is one of many such administration clients). It allows you to access and modify databases, but it does not contain any data itself. Your code connects directly to the MySQL database server and doesn't have anything to do with PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: You are not connecting to phpMyAdmin when you use a Mysql connection. The error is pretty clear, your credentials are bad. It depends on your installation but you can try.`$password = "mysql";` in your code, it's default password

Comment: In `save_data.php` you wrote `$password = "";` . I don't know why you made a new connection in this file instead of re-using the code in `baza.php`? It makes no sense why you didn't just put `require_once 'baza.php';` like you did in the `index.php` script?? If you notice, in baza.php you have defined completely different database credentials! Try to pay closer attention to the details in your code.

Comment: ok, I connected to the database, and why the edit button and delete button does not work?

Comment: How should we know? What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? That could describe 100 different issues. Do you get a specific error? Or does it behave unexpectedly in some specific way? Have you done any debugging, to try and narrow down the problem? If you need help with that I suggest deleting this question and posting a new one with a [mre] of the particular issue - most of the code you've shown here doesn't seem to be relevant to your editing or deleting functionality

Comment: Nothing happens after clicking edit and delete.

Comment: So did you do any basic debugging like i mentioned? It seems this buttons invoke JavaScript functions, so start by checking the console for JavaScript errors, and/or using the JavaScript debugger to see what happens. These are the absolute basics steps you should be taking before asking anyone about anything, in this kind of situation